# How to access derived type members that are not on abstracted type when you have an array of the abstracted type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Please view the following code blocks to give the question that follows proper context.

**Abstracted class**:

```
public abstract class Asset
{
    public GameObject Mode { get; set; }
    public AssetDimensions Dimensions { get; set; }
    public string BundleName { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Type { get; }

    public string Sku
    {
        get
        {
            return this._sku;
        }
    }

    private string _sku;

    public Asset(AssetConfig assetConfig)
    {
        this.Model = null;
        this.Dimensions = new AssetDimensions(assetConfig.dimensions);
        this.BundleName = assetConfig.bundleName;
        this.ModelName = assetConfig.modelName;

        this._sku = assetConfig.sku;
    }
}
```

**Derived class**:

```
public class SpecificAsset : Asset
{
    public SpecificAssetController Controller { get; set; }
    public override string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return this._type;
        }
    }

    private string _type;

    public SpecificAsset(AssetConfig assetConfig) : base(assetConfig)
    {
        this._type = "SpecificAsset";
    }
}
```

**Initialize List<`Asset`> and add an `SpecificAsset` to it**:

```
public List<Asset> Assets = new List<Asset>();

Assets.Add(new SpecificAsset(assetConfig));
```

Now because the of the List<`Asset`> declaration I get a `Asset does not contain a definition for Controller` when I attempt to access `Assets[0].Controller`

What would an idiomatic approach to obtaining this kind of dynamic functionality in C#? I need to be able to store different specific types in a collection and operate on their non-derived members. I'm fresh from JavaScript land where dogs can be cats, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the world of typed languages. Here you have to a) check if object is given type and if it is, then b) cast object to that type before access member in derived class.

Comment: @RistoM there a better way to do this? I will have to iterate through these assets and repetitious casting just seems like a design flaw.

Comment: If you are sure there is only SpecificAsset-insances, then initialize array with `List<SpecificAsset>`. If there can be both, you have to check type before casting (or get Invalid cast exception)

Comment: `SpecificAsset` was a generalization. There could be different specific assets types that derive from the base `Asset`.

Comment: Yep, and abstract class is good way to model that situation.. You can try that [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48468130/5789864) way also..

Comment: Is there something you specifically want to do with the `Controller`? Can it be described as a more general behaviour that would apply to all `Asset` types? If so, then one approach is to define a virtual method in the `Asset` class, then override that in the `SpecificAsset` class to perform the appropriate interaction with `Controller`. Afterwards, you can just blindly call that method for any given `Asset` to get the desired effect, rather than worrying about the type-specific `Controller` (or other implementation details).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple cast can be useful but not for many applications. I would recommend taking a different approach all together. How about using generics to let the implementation classes handle the property type (and keep the property in the base class for all to use).

```
public abstract class Asset<T>  where T : IController
{
    ...
    public T Controller { get; set; }
    ...
}
public interface IController
{
    void ContollerMethod();
}
```

And the implementation would look like this:

```
public class SpecificAsset : Asset<ControllerImpl>
{
    ....
}
public class ControllerImpl : IController 
{
    public void ControllerMethod()
    {
        //Some code here...
    }
}
```

This approach can work well when you need to have a property or two of a different types in a base class. This allows the class inheriting to define what type they will use. This isn't a great approach every time (an example might be if you want to have implementation class define more than 3 different types).

Edit: I'll also note a case where this makes things much easier. Consider the following code:

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    List<Asset<IController>> assets = new List<Asset<IController>>();
    //Populate assets list here
    foreach (Asset<IController> asset in assets)
    {
        asset.Controller.ControllerMethod();
        //Here we cannot cast to a specific type easily because we may not know them at runtime. 
        //With the generic, we can still make any appropriate calls and not know the specifics
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more in line with what I thought should be possible. I will implement this and get back to you, though this feels like it will be the accepted answer.

Comment: That is why my assets have a `Type` property so that this can be set when their config is parsed from JSON. Though it feels like it is an artifact of my JavaScript experience. I'm about 99% sure this is the approach I was after. Thank you very much. I'm going to up vote your answer and I will likely accept it later today.

Answer (score 0):

Try `((SpecificAsset)Assets[0]).Controller`. Ideally you would use [is and as casts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-safely-cast-by-using-as-and-is-operators) so that you get some sort of safety but if you're sure that they are always going to be derived from `Asset` then a hard cast is ok.

You should investigate [abstact classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract), you could create a `BaseAsset` class which has your common properties across all `Asset`s, `Asset` and `SpecificAsset` would also only have to implement properties specific to them. As for the typing of your list it can remain the same.

Comment: Ya I know this approach, but I figured there would be a better approached. I will need to iterate through this List and I don't want to have to cast repeatedly. Thank you though.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: This really doesn't work when you have more than one implementation class and are manipulating these at run time. Especially considering that most (if not all) libraries that utilize abstract classes will have multiple implementations.